# Swift - Play sound when near a Beacon

Tags: swift, xcode6, ibeacon, estimote

I bought some beacons and started to play with them following some tutorials.
I have a little problem now, with the following code I can successfully change the background color of my iPhone, but the sound (a 3 mins MP3) is looping after some seconds.

How can I modify my code to go ahead?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

    let knownBeacon = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
    if knownBeacon.count > 0 {
        let nearestBeacon = knownBeacon[0] as CLBeacon
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[nearestBeacon.minor.integerValue]

        if nearestBeacon.minor.integerValue == 15879 {
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!), fileTypeHint: "mp3", error: nil)
            if let sound = audioPlayer {
                sound.prepareToPlay()
                sound.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop is running as long as you have your beacon near by. You need to add some logic so it waits as long as you need before it can be called again.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an example with code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is running as long as you have a beacon near by. There's probably other ways of doing it, but something I can think of is using a simple NSTimer.

Add a bool in top of your project underneath class

```
var beaconEnabled : Bool = true
```

Change your code to something like this. Notice the "beaconEnabled = true" and the NSTimer after the play() function. Change the 300 seconds to whatever you need.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

    if beaconEnabled {

        let knownBeacon = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
        if knownBeacon.count > 0 {
            let nearestBeacon = knownBeacon[0] as CLBeacon
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[nearestBeacon.minor.integerValue]

            if nearestBeacon.minor.integerValue == 15879 {
                audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!), fileTypeHint: "mp3", error: nil)
                if let sound = audioPlayer {
                    sound.prepareToPlay()
                    sound.play()
                    beaconEnabled = false
                    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(300.0, target: self, selector: Selector("enableBeacon"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this function to enable your beacon again

```
func enableBeacon () {
    beaconEnabled = true
}
```

This will wait 300 seconds before it can play the sound again.